# What date format does Kronos Workforce Central expect?

Tags: xml, date, kronos-workforce-central

I have an XML request which asks the Kronos Workforce Central API for an employee's pay period total over a specified time period.

I am using `PeriodDateSpan = '2017/10/23 - 2017/10/30'` to specify the pay period, making sure to follow the typical `yyyy/mm/dd` format for dates

```
<Kronos_WFC version='1.0'>
    <Request Action='Load'>
        <Timesheet>
            <Employee>
                <PersonIdentity PersonNumber = '12345'/>
             </Employee>
             <Period>
                 <TimeFramePeriod PeriodDateSpan = '2017/10/23 - 2017/10/30'/>
             </Period>
         </Timesheet>
     </Request>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

When I send this request to my WFC access point `wfc/XmlService`, the server responds with an error stating that my value for `DatePeriodSpan` is not valid.

```
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0" WFCVersion="6.3.13.362" TimeStamp="10/31/2017 11:08AM GMT-04:00">
   <Response Status="Failure" Action="Load">
      <Error Message="WFP-00950 The value is not valid for the property - Name: PeriodDateSpan, Value: 2017/10/20 - 2017/10/27." ErrorCode="1102" AtIndex="0" PropertyName="PeriodDateSpan" PropertyValue="2017/10/20 - 2017/10/27"/>
   </Response></Kronos_WFC>
```

What date format does Kronos expect when specifying a `PeriodDateSpan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Kronos Workforce Central is configured to format long dates as `M/dd/yyyy`.

- `M`: Month number, no leading zero
- `dd`: Day number, leading zero
- `yyyy`: Year number, 4 digits

As an example, June 8, 2018 would be formatted as `6/08/2018`. The timespan specified in the question would be formatted as `<TimeFramePeriod PeriodDateSpan = '10/23/2017 - 10/30/2017'/>`

The date format may differ on a server-by-server basis, as configured by the server administrator (Setup -> System Configuration -> System Settings -> Locale).

**Assuming the date format has not been changed from defaults, below is a corrected XML request for an employee's Pay Period Total**

```
<Kronos_WFC version='1.0'>
    <Request Action='Load'>
        <Timesheet>
            <Employee>
                <PersonIdentity PersonNumber = '12345'/>
             </Employee>
             <Period>
                 <TimeFramePeriod PeriodDateSpan = '10/23/2017 - 10/30/2017'/>
             </Period>
         </Timesheet>
     </Request>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

---

**Tip**: If you need to determine the server's current date, you can send a `GetServerTime` request to make the server respond with it's date and time. This DateTime can be reused for requests which require a `ChangeDate` or `EffectiveDate`.

Request:

```
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0">
    <Request Object="ServerTime" Action="GetServerTime" />
</Kronos_WFC>
```

Response:

```
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0" WFCVersion="6.3.13.362" TimeStamp="10/31/2017 11:08AM GMT-04:00">
    <Response Status="Success" Object="ServerTime" Action="GetServerTime">
        <ServerTime DateTime="10/31/2017 11:08AM" KronosTimeZone="(GMT -05:00) Eastern Time"/>
    </Response>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

Additionally, the root `<Kronos_WFC>` tag in the server's response should always include a `TimeStamp` attribute with the current date and time on the server.

```
TimeStamp="10/31/2017 11:08AM GMT-04:00"
```